# Need to add user defined field to add product in shopp plugin wordpress

Tags: wordpress, shopp

WordPress: Version 4.4.2
Shopp Plugin

I Need to add a user defined field to add product in Shopp plugin WordPress which will be used for XML generation and further for communication with one of the Payment Gateways.
Tried for clues surfing online but didn't find any.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? Where is this field going to be inserted, used, what kind of data are you looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add fields to the checkout form that are specific to the payment gateway that is used you could take a look at this filter

[shopp_checkout_gateway_inputs](https://shopplugin.net/api/shopp_checkout_gateway_inputs/)

This should be added to payment gateway file you are creating.

If you are looking for collecting additional order info on the checkout page you could use this bit of code

[shopp('checkout.order-data')](https://shopplugin.net/api/checkout-order-data/)

This should be added to checkout.php.

If you are looking for collecting additional customer info on the checkout page you could use this bit of code

[shopp('checkout.customer-info')](https://shopplugin.net/api/checkout-customer-info/)

This should be added to checkout.php.

Comment: Hey thanks RST :) , 'shopp_checkout_gateway_inputs' helped me but alas that i revisited the site very late
I have 1 more concern reg the same. how to displayed the posted data in these fields on error display. $_POST or $_SESSION does not work for me :(

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a support forum. If you post your code people can help you solve issues. You can always find yourself a Shopp developer in case you are stuck.